# How to draw image created in try/catch?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, try-catch, awt

I'm learning Java, and I've converted `File` type into `Image` using `IOException`, but how can I use my new `Image` outside of `try/catch`?

```java
try {
        File obraz = new File("C:\\Users\\ender\\Pictures\\logo.jpg");
        Image image = ImageIO.read(obraz);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.drawImage(image);
}
```

Because now IntelliJ does not recognize image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case - as `paintComponent` will be called often, and you want to load the image just once, put the image in a field.

```
private Image image;

...() {
    try {
        File obraz = new File("C:\\Users\\ender\\Pictures\\logo.jpg");
        image = ImageIO.read(obraz);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

...() throws IOException {
    File obraz = new File("C:\\Users\\ender\\Pictures\\logo.jpg");
    image = ImageIO.read(obraz);
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    if (image != null) {
        g2.drawImage(image);
    }
}
```

I have shown two solutions:

- catching the exception as done now: but one should do something, give an error message to the user that file logo.jpg does not exist
- passing the exception on by throws, often the better solution.

The convention is to use `@Override` as this catches typos like `public void paintComponent(Graphics2D g)` or `public void painComponent(Graphics g)`.

Comment: Thank you, I'm really grateful